# Qt hangs when calling QApplication

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just did a fresh install of Qt Creator so I have the latest version.  I opened my project that I was working on from the previous install of Qt Creator. It complies without errors but seams to hang on this line:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Here is the full main.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include<QTextStream>
#include<QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    qDebug()<<1;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<2;
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

When it runs my application will open displaying the window but nothing works.

Here is the applciation's output:

> Starting /home/bandito/programming/build-etf-ipo-Unnamed-Debug/etf-ipo...
>
> 1

As you can see qDebug()<<1; is called but the application never makes it to qDebug()<<2;

I also tried replacing QApplication with QGuiApplication and QCoreApplication but both request the QApplication be called also.

Comment: I have no clue about this. Maybe you could try creating an empty Qt project and see if the same problem exists?

Comment: How can you see the window, if you never get to the line that creates the window? Before outputting 2, the windows does not exist!

Comment: I tried creating a new application. I get the same result. I also tried reinstalling the Ubuntu and qt creator from scratch. This time I get the same results plus alot of gtk errors. I did install the modules from the repository so maybe that's the problem?